# how to auto add backslash in vscode when i press 'enter'?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Writing python in vscode does not automatically add a backslash when I press 'enter'.
Is there any way to implement automatic backslash addition?

Comment: Do you need to use vscode? IDE’s like PyCharm work better for specifically python features - and I know they have this. There is probably a way to add it yourself otherwise with a plugin.

Comment: @olijeffers0n now, i use vscode as my ide to write python, before that i use pycharm, i know pycharm has this feature, so i want to know if there are plugins feature or other configuration in vscode that can do this.

Comment: I program Python for years and never used the backslash on `enter`, you can use multi-command to combine the double keystroke

Comment: @olijeffers0n This kind of opinion based discussions (IDE1 vs. IDE2) are not what like to see on Stack Overflow. Please keep your contributions to the IDE in the question.